# with javascript looping issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Developing a program which allows people to enter the office based on there names, this is just a test program to practice and develop my skills in javascript... why does the "try again" statement get executed when there is a successful match between the users input and the my array?

```
    // program to allow people to enter the office
console.log("Welcome to Company X, Please follow the")

let Employees = ["Harry","Dom","j"]
let visitors = prompt("Hi, Enter your name")
let attempts = 0
let alert = 2

for(let i = 0; i<Employees.length;i++) {
   while(visitors!=Employees[i] && attempts<alert) {
   attempts = attempts + 1 
   visitors = prompt("try again")
  }  
   if(visitors===Employees[i]) {
   console.log("Please move forward")
   } 
  } 
   
if (attempts>=alert) {
  console.log("Security ON-ROUTE!")
}
```

Comment: If you enter "Dom", then when you get to the `while` loop `i` will be 0 and the comparison will fail, and it will keep failing because `i` doesn't change.

Comment: Lesson 1: [Java != JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245069). Please [edit] tags and remove unrelated language.

Comment: @pointy how would this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

let's think about what happens here.

first, you have "Harry" at `Employees[0]` and let's say I entered "Harry" as "visitors"

so the while loop have false condition and it will run `console.log("Please move forward")`

but it will not Stop, now the `Employees[1]` will be "Dom" so the While loop condition will be true and will ask you again for name, etc...

so one of the solutions is to add:

```html
 if(visitors===Employees[i]) {
       console.log("Please move forward")
       i = Employees.length ;
       }
```

but it will work only if you follow the order of the Employees Array.

Comment: Hey Thanks .. I found the issue in hindsight use a break command in the if and while


  
   if(visitors===Employees[i]) {
   console.log("Please move forward")
   break
   } 
  } 
   
if (attempts>=alert) {
 console.log("Security ON-ROUTE!")
}